# JS List intersection for my use case

Tags: javascript, list, intersection

I am a javascript newbie so bear with me. I have lists as so:

```
var list1 = ['a','b','c'];
var list2 = ['c','d','e'];
var list3 = ['f','g'];
```

As you see, list1 and list2 intersect at 'c' while list3 is disjoint from both list1 and list2.
The result should be

```
['a','b','c','d','e'],['f','g'] // Two arrays
```

We have combined list1 and list2 since they intersect while leaving list3 as is. Another example:

```
var list1 = ['a','b','c'];
var list2 = ['d','e','f'];
var list3 = ['f','g','a'];
```

Here we see list1 and list2 don't intersect, list1 intersects with list3 at 'a' and list2 intersects list3 at 'f'. So since all 3 intersect, the result returned would be:

```
['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'] // One array
```

Any help is appreciated
KA

PS: I did search the site for a similar problem and I came across one [intersection of n lists via JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837295/intersection-of-n-lists-via-js) Its similar but doesn't serve my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two-list intersection and union functions, you can get what you want with this logic:

```
var lists; // initialized with the lists you want to process
var merged = [];
for each list a in lists {
    for each list b in merged {
        if intersect(a,b) != empty {
            remove b from merged;
            a = union(a,b);
        }
    }
    add a to merged;
}
```

You just have to be a little careful about removing b from merged while you are looping through all the elements of merged. It might be simpler to iterate through merged from the last to the first element.
The [underscore library](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) is a nice place to find functions for intersection and union.

Comment: I tried your sudo code on paper and it seems to work ! No way my little mind would have processed this :) One thing I didn't understand was your concern about removing b from merged and iterating from last to first on merged. Could you explain? Thumbs up for the pseudo code though (Tried to do this but don't have enough reputation :( ).

Comment: Say that you're looping through `merged` by incrementing an index `i` and you need to remove element `b` (which is at position `i`). Typically, you'd do this by moving the last element of `merged` to `i` and shorten the list length by one. If you increment `i` in the same pass through the loop, then you will have skipped testing the element that had been last (and is now where `b` used to be). Starting at the end and decrementing the index avoids this problem.

Comment: I tried out the pseudo code today and it works perfect ! Thanks Ted.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<script>
    Array.prototype.unique = function() {  
        var temp = {}, len = this.length;
        for(var i=0; i < len; i++)  {  
            if(typeof temp[this[i]] == "undefined") {
                temp[this[i]] = 1;
            }  
        }  
        this.length = 0;
        len = 0;
        for(var i in temp) {  
            this[len++] = i;
        }  
        return this;  
    }  

    var list1 = ['a','b','c'];
    var list2 = ['c','d','e'];
    var list3 = ['f','g'];


    start = new Date().getTime(); 
    var list = list1.concat(list2).concat(list3).unique(); 
</script>
```

Comment: You don't get two arrays out of that as OP wants with the first example.