# How to find the Intersection of n arrays

Tags: coffeescript

I have n arrays or variable length

```
arr1 = [1,2,3]
arr2 = [1,3,5,8]
....
```

How can I compute the intersection of those n arrays ?

Comment: Do the arrays always hold integers?

Comment: @muistooshort: yes, only integers

Answer (score 2):

Consider checking out [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library. It provides [function](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#intersection) for what you need and a bunch of other usefull functions.

Example from docs:

```
_.intersection([1, 2, 3], [101, 2, 1, 10], [2, 1]);
=> [1, 2]
```

Simple plain JS implementation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5837541/539686). Same idea in CoffeeScript:

```
intersect_all = (lists) ->
  if lists.length is 0
    return []
  else return lists[0]  if lists.length is 1
  partialInt = lists[0]
  i = 1

  while i < lists.length
    partialInt = intersection(partialInt, lists[i])
    i++
  partialInt
```

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is to use hashsets:

```
function hashset (elements) {
  var i, set = {};
  if (!Array.isArray(elements)) return elements;
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    set[elements[i]] = true;
  }
  return set;
};

function intersect (a, b) {
  var k
    , s1 = hashset(a)
    , s2 = hashset(b)
    , s3 = {}
  for (k in s1) {
    if (s2[k]) s3[k] = true;
  }
  return s3;
};

Object.keys(intersect(arr1,arr2));
// ["1", "3"]
```

You will find [CoffeeScript source of this code, benchmarks for it](/questions/20489535/efficient-and-async-way-to-check-if-at-least-one-element-of-an-array-is-also-an/20490628#20490628) and some additional information [in this question](/questions/20489535/efficient-and-async-way-to-check-if-at-least-one-element-of-an-array-is-also-an).

If you're going to to intersect huge arrays then I strongly recommend you to use this approach.

Comment: There is a big caveat here: this only works if the arrays hold strings or if you're okay with comparing the elements as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Either just use something like [_.intersection](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#intersection) or [study the source of that implementation](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-52) and rewrite it if you like.